Z(t) having a positive local minima or a negative local maxima?
In H.M.Edwards'  Riemann's Zeta Function, on page 176, he writes: "If there were a point at which the graph of $Z(t)$ came near to $Z = 0$ but did not actually cross it  -that is, if $Z$ had a small positive local minimum or a small negative local maximum - then the Riemann hypothesis would be contradicted."
where $Z(t)$ is defined as:
$$Z(t) = e^{i\nu(t)}  \zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)$$ and
$$\nu(t) = \Im \log\prod\left(\frac{it}{2} - \frac{3}{4}\right) - \frac{t}{2}\log \pi$$
The first half of the quote does not make sense to me. Because if $Z$ has a negative local maximum for example, then this would imply RH is false which would imply $t$ is not real which would imply $Z$ is complex which would imply that negative local maxima has no meaning. What is happening here?

$Z$ is a real function (the definition of $Z$ has nothing to do with RH) whose zeroes are precisely the zeroes of $\zeta$ on the critical line; the falsity of RH is equivalent to $Z$ having fewer zeroes than "it should have" (under RH all the nontrivial zeroes of zeta are zeroes of $Z$, so RH false means zeta has more zeroes than $Z$ so to speak) and that is implied by the property mentioned by Edwards (small positive minimum or small negative maximum which intuitively means exactly that $Z$ fails to have a zero where it should actually have one); the rigorous proof is in Edwards and is easy

But when $Z(t)$ has a negative local maximum, RH is false since $\frac{Z'}{Z}$ is monotone between consecutive zeros of $Z$ only under RH. This should imply that $t$ is no longer real and  there in lies my circular thinking perhaps.

Littlewood mentioned some indications against the Riemann hypothesis including this one. Apparently , those indications were not taken serious , and still almost all mathematicians believe in the truth of RH , despite some issues like the Lehmer-phenomenon.

$Z$ is a real function with zeroes the critical line of zeta zeroes; if the RH is true than $Z'/Z$ is monotonic between the zeroes of $Z$ (proof in Edwards not hard) so $Z'$ (real function on a line) must have interlacing zeroes with $Z$ as it cannot have two in between consecutive zeroes of $Z$ by the above and must have one by Rolle; this precludes positive minimum or negative maximum of $Z$ just by basic calculus (see graph of such); hence by contradiction if such happens RH must be false; nothing to do with non critical zeroes directly - all is implicit in the monotonicity of $Z'/Z$

The proof of the monotonicity of $Z’/Z$ assumes RH which assumes $t$ to be real. In other words if $t$ is real then $Z’/Z$ is always monotone which implies there is no possibility of positive local minima or negative local maxima of $Z$ between consecutive zeros of $Z$. $t$ is either real or not. If $t$ is real then there is no possibility of a positive local minima or negative local maxima. If $t$ is complex those local extrema do not make sense since $Z$ becomes complex.

you are completely misunderstanding the statement - here everything is about the real function $Z(t)$ nothing complex; the monotonicity result says that if RH true then $Z'/Z$ monotonic between the zeroes of $Z$; this is equivalent (by basic logic) to: if $Z'/Z$ NOT monotonic between zeroes, then RH is false; that's it, no complex zeroes  or values of $t$ involved
